# Flagging on mobile error

Tags: bug, flagging, ios-app

I am using the mobile app and tried to flag a comment on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2222344/123230) as obsolete (the comment has since been deleted). The app told me that an error occurred and that I should report it on meta.

Comment: The Op there deleted their comment shortly after you deleted yours. Could be that the error occurred because you tried to flag an already-deleted comment. In that case, it would be nice if a specific error saying that would be raised, rather than a generic error. But it may well be a too rare thing to justify the time needed to change the code.